# NotificationCenter - text transfer between views

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

MainViewControler.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showAlertMessage(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationAlertMessage"), object: errorMessage.self) 

}


@objc func showAlertMessage(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! \(notification.title)")
}
```

AlertStruct.swift:

```
struct errorMessage{
    var title: String?
    var description: String?
}
```

Propierties.swift

```
func showError(){
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationAlertMessage"), object: errorMessage(title: "tytuł", description: "description"))
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    showError()   
}
```

Propierties.swift is child in containerView MainViewControler.

I would like to display the function ShowAlertMessage in my MainViewControler with data sent from Propierties -> func showError ()

How to do it? My code does not want to compile / work correctly :(

Comment: It's never a good idea to show an alert message or run a timer with viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct...Just update below method

```
@objc func showAlertMessage(notification: NSNotification) {

    let object = notification.object as! errorMessage
     print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! \(object.title)")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, tested

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showAlertMessage(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationAlertMessage"), object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationAlertMessage"), object: nil, userInfo: ["object": ErrorMessage(title: "tytuł", description: "description")])
}

@objc func showAlertMessage(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let errorMessage = notification.userInfo?["object"] as? ErrorMessage {
        print("\(errorMessage.title), \(errorMessage.description)")
    }
}
```